# MVC3 Actionlink with confirmation dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, confirmation

Can I show a confirmation message for an `ActionLink`?

Do I need to use javascript? Is it possible without it?

Could you give some example for me?

Thank you.

```
//I want to make a confirmation message appear before the link opens.
@Html.ActionLink("Checkout and view order list", "Order", "Order")
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using the overload `Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object RouteValues, object HtmlAttributes)` and some javascript, you can do the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Checkout and view order list", "Order", "Order", null, new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to click this link?')" })
```

This will add the HTML attribute onclick, which will execute the specified javascript when the link is clicked. If an onclick event on a link (or a form's submit button) returns false, the action (following the link, posting the form) doesn't happen. The `confirm(message)` function shows the user a confirmation dialog with the specified message, and returns either true or false depending on the user's response.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: don't use this answer, use the other one from Jim.

You won't be able to use `ActionLink` - you'll have to write some JavaScript (such as that listed [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php)) to pop up a confirmation. You can use `Url.Action` to generate the URL that the javascript will eventually use for the post or get endpoint.

My javascript is bad, but I think this gets the idea across:

```
<a href="javascript:confirmation();">Checkout and view order list</a>

<script>
function confirmation() {
 var answer = confirm("Confirm?")
 if(answer) {
  // Do something here, post or get
  window.location = @Url.Action("Order", "Order");
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ActionLink can still be used. It just can't do the confirmation on its own.

Comment: Yeah, ActionLink has a ton of overloads (sometimes it can get messy trying to use the right one). Since RouteValues and HtmlAttributes are pretty flexible as well, you can do quite a bit with ActionLink

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a button that already called an action:

```
<input id="ButtonDelete" type="button" value="Delete Experiment" class="big-nevigation-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteExperiment", "Experiment", new { experimentId = Model.ExperimentId })'" />
```

After reading Jim's answer, I changed it to the following:

```
<input id="ButtonDelete" type="button" value="Delete Experiment" class="big-nevigation-button" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete experiment???')) location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteExperiment", "Experiment", new { experimentId = Model.ExperimentId })'" />
```

And it works greate!
Thanks Jim!!

Answer (score -1):

in MVC Core, I used this, but still in JavaScript

```
 <button type="submit"  
  asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"
  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">
  </button>
```