# MVC 4 Actionlink to prompt Jquery Confirmation Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm implementing an actionlink to perform delete. Initially was using javascript confirmation box. Due to customer request to change the confirmation box header text, i need to use jquery confirmation dialog. It will straight perform delete without prompting the dialog box when i click the link. Please help me. Thanks!

My View & Actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "SURV_Admin_Group_Delete", "SURV_Admin", new { id = Model[i].GroupID }, new { @class = "modal" })

<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

Jquery dialog script:

```
 $('.modal').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);

        function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
            $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");

            // Define the Dialog and its properties.
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                title: "Modal",
                height: 250,
                width: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        return true;
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

My Delete Controller:

```
 public ActionResult SURV_Admin_Group_Delete(int id)
        {
            SURV_Group_Model surv_group_model = db.SURV_Group_Model.Find(id);
            db.SURV_Group_Model.Remove(surv_group_model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("SURV_Admin_Create_Group");
        }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for your feedback. It's a POST on delete controller actually. I have no idea why it straight delete without trigger the jquery script. Something wrong with my jquery i guess..

Comment: @StephenMuecke, noted that its a GET. Hmm any idea to make it better? Can you provide some sample code for my reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198226/mvc3-actionlink-with-confirmation-dialog